# Jquery slide down example

Tags: jquery, hide, slide

I have a div called "bottomtabdivright" and with some css when I hover is show the div called "showme" . Example on [greenieproducts.com](http://greenieproducts.com/portable-solar-generator-sunxgen-800-80w-monocrystalline-solar-panel800w-power-inverter105-amph-deep-cycle-battery/) in the description part ....

I'd like for the div "showme" to slide down and appear instead of just bam its there. I think this would be done with some jquery code ? This is the first time that I kind of dig into jquery and I'm just not sure where to start.
Here's what I got so far

```
#showme {display:none;}
#bottomdivtabright:hover #showme {border:3px solid white;outline:3px solid black;background-color:black;display:block;width:450px;position:absolute;right:5px;top:48px;padding:10px;}
```

U guys are amazing, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#bottomdivtabright').hover(function() {  
        $('#showme').slideDown();
    }, function() { 
        $('#showme').slideUp();
    });
});
```

Comment: Hello thank you so much for your fast response, I've inserted     <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#bottomdivtabright').hover(function() {  
        $('#showme').slideDown();
    }, function() { 
        $('#showme').slideUp();
    });
});
</script> in header.php, but its not doing anything, where did I screw up :)

Comment: Something's conflicting with your jQuery installation. See the error console: `Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Window] is not a function`

Comment: Couold you please give more to go on, so maybe I can try to find out how to fix the problem ?

Comment: Do you have any other libraries installed on the site that use the `$` namespace?

Comment: Maybe this I added to show img only when page finished loaded ...      $(document).ready(function () {<div class="ngg_slideshow widget">
   <div id="ngg-slideshow-2-2-1" class="ngg-widget-slideshow" style="height:120px;width:350px;">
<div id="ngg-slideshow-2-2-1-loader" class="ngg-slideshow-loader" style="height:120px;width:350px;">
<img src="http://www.ehowtodrywall.com/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/images/loader.giff49bb?3f49bb" alt="" />
</div></div>});

});
</script>